# How to concatenate rows when joining two tables

Tags: mysql

I have tow tables and I am executing a join statement on them . When i do there's multiple columns having same key and different values. 
Is there any way to concatenate these values separated by commas?

This is the join query

```
SELECT A.bucket_id,B.id FROM coms_category A JOIN product_category B ON A.category_url=B.url;
```

And a sample of a result is like this

```
+-----------+-----+
| bucket_id | id  |
+-----------+-----+
|      1261 | 692 |
|      1157 | 600 |
|      1222 | 600 |
```

As 600 comes twice . My desired output is **1157,1222 against 600 .**

I have tried

```
SELECT B.id,A.bucket_id GROUP_CONCAT(A.bucket_id SEPARATOR ', ')FROM coms_category A JOIN product_category B ON A.category_url=B.url GROUP BY B.id;
```

but it didn't work .

Comment: Consider handling display issues in application code

Comment: Change `A.bucket_id GROUP_CONCAT(A.bucket_id SEPARATOR ', ')` to `GROUP_CONCAT(A.bucket_id SEPARATOR ', ')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use sub-query  ,1st `group by` will remove duplication

```
select T.id ,GROUP_CONCAT(T.bucket_id SEPARATOR ', ')
 from (
  SELECT B.id,A.bucket_id 
    FROM coms_category A 
    JOIN product_category B 
    ON A.category_url=B.url 
    GROUP BY B.id,A.bucket_id
) as T group by T.id
```